# Next.js error right after creating next app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

when I create a new next app and try to run the server i keep getting this error

```
./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\Usersuddin\Desktop\asiqur\asp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js' in 'C:\Users\uddin\Desktop\asiqur\asp\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev
```

I tried reinstalling it multiple times but its the same error

I change nothing in the files yet the error occurs

[image]

Comment: The path: `'C:\Usersuddin\Desktop\asiqur\asp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js'` clearly has an error compared to: `'C:\Users\uddin\Desktop\asiqur\asp\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev`. No `\` between `Users` and `uddin`. Maybe check the `path` environment variable on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue for any directory whose name starts with `ud` : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36078

Renaming your users directory would be a pain! Maybe try putting the Next.js project somewhere other than your users directory, to avoid having `uddin` in the path?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. I changed my folder name